# Using SQLT_BDOUBLE for NUMBER(x,y) Oracle columns

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

In my application, I have created Oracle columns as `NUMBER(x,y)` and used `SQLT_FLT` for bind and define application double variables for writing and reading data to and from Oracle database as follows.

```
b_IsErr = OCIDefineByPos(p_sql, &p_dfn, p_DBCon->p_err, iPos, 
    (dvoid*)pdValue, sizeof(double), SQLT_FLT, 0, 0, 0, 
    OCI_DEFAULT);

b_IsErr = OCIBindByPos(p_sql, &p_bnd, p_DBCon->p_err, iPos,
    (dvoid*)pdValue, sizeof(double), SQLT_FLT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

But, due to the possible precision loss I tried to use the Oracle recommended IEEE754 data types `BINARY_DOUBLE`. According to the Oracle guide the bind and define functions should be called with `SQLT_BDOUBLE` for dealing with `BINARY_DOUBLE` data types.

But my application still uses some `NUMBER(x,y)` columns and I tried to use the same way (`SQLT_BDOUBLE`) for dealing with `NUMBER(x,y)` columns and seems it is working fine.

I was unable to find any document contains whether this is correct or not.
Someone know the OCI please assist.